# Paging: Find Object-Position (Page) to Display

Tags: sql, angularjs, odata, breeze, paging

I'm using .take() and .skip() for paging with a table.

Now when I "insert" an entity into the database, I reload my table (new query). Now I would like to jump to this new object inside the table and highlight it.

Is there an elegant solution to find on what page the new object is and then use skip/take to jump to the correct page?

**Edit:**

Maybe Breeze/OData could natively support paging by allowing to specify a page-size in the query and which page to deliver (instead of using take and skip and calculating it on the client).

If this was the case, the parameter for "which page to deliver" could, instead of being an integer, also be a sub-query which would be executed on the resulting data before it gets "taked and skipped" to find out, on which page the object(s) are visible and use this as "page to deliver".

**Edit 2:**

Added the idea to Breeze UserVoice: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6824937-support-paging-natively

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting idea, but I don't know of any really elegant solution to accomplish this. Conceptually, how would you expect this to work under the covers?

Comment: I edited my question with a suggestion/idea. I'd be happy to read your thoughts on that if you're still interested.

Comment: Was my Comment/Edit any useful?

Comment: The idea is interesting but I'm a little leery of adding complexity that has a limited number of use cases.  However, please add this to the breeze user voice , and if it gets sufficient interest we will look seriously at adding something. see: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/filters/top